# In $S_{3}$ what is the group generated by $(123)$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

In $S_{3}$ what is the group generated by $(123)$?

Is there a way to find the elements of the group generated by $(123)$?

Comment: Yes, compute $(123)^2$, $(123)^3$, etc. until you find the identity permutation.

Comment: If you do as fkraiem suggests, it will not take very long, I assure you :)

Comment: Any subgroup generated by a single element is called a *cyclic* subgroup, for a reason that will become obvious if you do the computation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why yes! Let $g = (123)$. As $S_3$ is a finite group, there is some $n$ such that $g^n = e$, $e$ being the identity element. So to find the group generated by $g$, calculate powers of $g$ until you find the identity: $g, g^2, ..., g^n$. It shouldn't take very long.

Comment: Is $n$ related to the order of $S_{3}$?

Comment: @Anonymous Yes, it is at most 6, which is the order of $S_3$.

Comment: The order $n$ of any element $g$ of a finite group $G$ is a divisor of the order of $G$. Thus in this particular case, $n \ | \ 6$. That is, $n = 1, 2, 3$ or $6$.

Comment: Does $(123)^{n}=e$ belong in the group generated by $(123)$?

Comment: It had better, otherwise the object we have generated is not a subgroup of $S_3$ or a group in its own right.